# RuntimeMXBean when querying from jolokia api with JDK 11, it is returning 500 internal server Error in response

Tags: java, http-status-code-500, jolokia, mxbean

I have java application which uses **JDK 11** and attached **Jolokia-1.6.2** agent to it which I used to query Mbeans and get metrics but when I query for this mbean "java.lang:type=Runtime" it is returning 500 
You can find full json error message in this link https://jsonformatter.org/60604e

But I installed same application with JDK 8 and same **Jolokia-1.6.2** and I tried querying the same mbean it is working fine with response as expected with status code 200.

*curl localhost:8080/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Runtime*

Can't able to figure out what is going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

got the solution in updated JDK version (Java version > 8) they don't allow request like

*curl localhost:8080/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Runtime*

we need to specify the paths like Uptime,StartTime and it is working,

*curl localhost:8080/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Runtime/Uptime*